# Set heap memory for neo4j-admin import

Tags: java, neo4j, jvm

I'm tying to load a graph of several hundred million nodes using the `neo4j-admin import` tool to load the data from csv. The import will run for about two hours but then crashes with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1969)
at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2557)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.BadCollector$RelationshipsProblemReporter.getReportMessage(BadCollector.java:209)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.BadCollector$RelationshipsProblemReporter.message(BadCollector.java:195)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.BadCollector.processEvent(BadCollector.java:93)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.BadCollector$$Lambda$110/603650290.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.neo4j.concurrent.AsyncEvents.process(AsyncEvents.java:137)
at org.neo4j.concurrent.AsyncEvents.run(AsyncEvents.java:111)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've been trying to adjust my max and initial heap size settings in a few different ways. First I tried simply creating a `HEAP_SIZE=` variable before running the command to load the data as described [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/neo4j-admin/#neo4j-admin-environment-variables) and I tried setting the heap size on the JVM like this:

`export JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms100g -Xmx100g`

but whatever I setting I use when the import starts I get the same report:

```
Available resources:
  Total machine memory: 1.48 TB
  Free machine memory: 95.00 GB
  Max heap memory : 26.67 GB
  Processors: 48
  Configured max memory: 1.30 TB
  High-IO: true
```

As you can see, I'm building this on a large server that should have plenty of resources available. I'm assuming I'm not setting the JVM parameters correctly for Neo4j but I can't find anything online showing me the correct way to do this.

What might be causing my GC memory error and how can I resolve it? Is this something I can resolve by throwing more resources at the JVM and if so, how do I do that so the neo4j-admin import tool can use it?

`RHEL 7` `Neo4j CE 3.4.11` `Java 1.8.0_131`

Comment: The HEAP_SIZE environmental variable should be the way to go, can you add that snippet in of how you tried to set this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by increasing the maximum heap memory. The problem was I wasn't setting the heap memory allocation correctly.

It turns out there was a simple solution; it was just a matter of when I tried to set the heap memory. Initially, I had tried the command `export JAVA_OPTS='-server -Xms300g -Xmx300g'` at the command line *then* run my bash script to call `neo4j-admin import`. This was not working, `neo4j-admin import` continued to use the same heap space configuration regardless.

The solution was to simple include the command to set the heap memory in the shell script that called `neo4j-admin import`. My shell script ended up looking like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

export JAVA_OPTS='-server -Xms300g -Xmx300g'

/usr/local/neo4j-community-3.4.11/bin/neo4j-admin import \
--ignore-missing-nodes=true \
--database=mag_cs2.graphdb \
--multiline-fields=true \
--high-io=true \
```

This seems super obvious but it took me almost a week to realize what I needed to change. Hopefully, this saves someone else the same headache.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for describing your issue. I used your solution to address a similar problem in which neo4j was allocating too much to heap memory, causing the import to drag.

In my case, I was trying to import a database with a large number of relationships (1800+). I noticed inconsistent performance: sometimes, the import would be fast; other times, it would crawl. I noticed that during fast imports, the status messages would indicate that import was working with groups of relationships--e.g.:

```
#Relationship <-- Relationship 1-1824/1824
```

During slow imports, the status messages would indicate that import was working its way through individual relationships--e.g.:

```
<-- Relationship 6/1824  
<-- Relationship> 7/1824
```

etc.

Finally, I noticed the warning that had been at the beginning of the import all along:

> ```
> WARNING: heap size 1.705GiB is unnecessarily large for completing this import.
> The abundant heap memory will leave less memory for off-heap importer caches. Suggested heap size is 1.003GiB
> ```

Because the neo4.conf file for my neo4j instance does not set `dbms.memory.heap.initial_size`, neo4j was using a heuristic to over-allocate [heap memory](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/memory-configuration/). Apparently, there wasn't enough memory left for the import to work with large groups of relationships, so it was doing a lot of swapping.

Following the recommendation here, I set the max heap size to the value recommended by the warning (in this case, 1.003G) immediately before running import. The result:

```
IMPORT DONE in 9m 10s 102ms.
```